# Configuring Typescript to work with html modules

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm trying to set up a project using typescript and webpack, however I'm unable to bundle html files during the build process.

I'm expecting `index.ts` to import all `.html` files as strings (it can import `.ts` files just fine), this will then cause webpack to bundle them using `file-loader` and place them in `dist/examples` (so if I had more `.html` files I would import them here and they'd end up in `dist/examples` too).

I have tried both relative and absolute names for the import, but I get the error `TS2307: Cannot find module './file.html'` when run with both webpack and when I try and do it manually with `tsc -p src/tsconfig.json`.

I'm fairly new to typescript and this is the first time I've worked with `.d.ts` files but from what I understand the `index.d.ts` file should tell typescript to resolve all `.html` files as strings.

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'main', 'index.ts'),
    html: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'res', 'html', 'index.ts')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          configFile: 'src/tsconfig.json',
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'res', 'html'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: 'examples',
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.html', '.js' ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

### src/tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../dist/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types", "../types"],
  },
  "include": [
        "main/**/*",
        "res/html/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": []
}
```

### types/index.d.ts

```
declare module '*.html' {
  const value: string;
  export default value
}
```

### src/res/html/index.ts

```
import test from './test'
import file from './file.html'
```

### src/res/html/file.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>FILE</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your `tsconfig.json`, are you sure the directory `types/` is available from `"include"`?

Comment: looks like that was it, I thought declaring `typeRoots` would include that directory for types (because `node_modules/@types` works just fine), @Paleo if you copy that as an answer I'll mark the question as answered so you can get the credit

Comment: OK, It's done..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your directory "types/" includes a file with the following content:

```
declare module "html!*" {
    const value: string
    export default value
}
```

This directory must be accessible from the included paths (the option `"include"` in the file `tsconfig.json`).

Notice that the [`"typeRoots"` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) should not be used to include your own types. It is the option to make the TypeScript compiler mechanism  configurable when it uses the `@types` system of npm.

Comment: For me, what worked was this: ```declare module "*.html" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}```